# Dual-Side Templating vs. Server-Side DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, jquery-mobile, jsdom

I'm making an app that requires dynamic content be fully rendered on the page for search engine bots - a problem, potentially, should I use JS templating to control the content. Web spiders are supposedly getting better at indexing RIA sites, but I don't want to risk it. Also, as mobile internet is still spotty in most places, it seems like a good practice to maximize the server load initially to ensure that basic functionality/styles/dynamic content show up on your pages, even if the client hasn't downloaded any JS libraries.

That's how  I stumbled upon dual-side templating:

> Problem: How can you allow for dynamic, Ajax-style, rendering in the browser, but at the same time output it from the server upon initial page load?
>
> c. 2010: Dual-Side Templating A single template is used on both browser and server, to render content wherever it’s appropriate – typically the server as the page loads and the browser as the app progresses. For example, blog comments. You output all existing comments from the server, using your server-side template. Then, when the user makes a new comment, you render a preview of it – and the final version – using browser-side templating.

I want to try dual-side templating with Node.js and Eco templates, but I don't know how to proceed. I'm new to JavaScript and all things Node.

[Node-Lift](https://github.com/dodo/node-lift/blob/master/src/example/server.coffee) is said to help, but I don't understand what it's doing or why.

Can someone provide a high level overview of how you might use dual-templating in the context of a mobile web app?

Where does [server-side DOM manipulation with jQuery and JSDOM](http://blog.marksoper.net/Server-side-DOM-manipulation-in-Nodejs-with-JSDOM-JQuery-and-Mustache-Templates-April-25-2011.html) fit in to the equation?

TIA

Comment: [dustjs](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/) and [express-dust](https://github.com/davglass/express-dust) will allow for dual-side templating. The alternative is JSDOM and [weld](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/micro-templates-are-dead)

Comment: What are the pros/cons of using JSDOM + weld vs dustjs + express? When using JSDOM + weld, is it necessary for the client to download script files in the head of your document?

Comment: I plan to port weld or something weld-like to the client at some point. I'll let you know if I succeed with something stable.

Comment: weld works on the browser already..

Answer (score 0):

Dav Glass gave a great talk about this last year: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzCnUXEvF84

And here is a blog article that goes over some of the details: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/04/09/node-js-yui-3-dom-manipulation-oh-my/

Comment: Yep - that's the one that originally piqued my interest.